# Howto use QCA(http://delta.affinix.com/qca/) with Qt4.7 (Qt Creator)?

Tags: qt, qt4, cryptography, qt-creator

I want to use the QCA Library with QT4.7 and QTCreator as IDE.
I downloaded the "qca-2.0.2-mingw" Version and try to link them in my ".Pro"-file:

```
QT       += core
QT       -= gui
LIBS += -L"\qca-2.0.2-mingw\lib\"
LIBS += -lqca2

CONFIG *= qt
CONFIG   += console
CONFIG   -= app_bundle

INCLUDEPATH += "\qca-2.0.2-mingw\include\QtCrypto"
INCLUDEPATH += "\qca-2.0.2-mingw\bin"

TARGET = untitled1

TEMPLATE = app

LINKAGE = -lqca
CONFIG(debug, debug|release) {
    windows:LINKAGE = -lqcad
    mac:LINKAGE = -lqca_debug
}
LIBS += $$LINKAGE

SOURCES += main.cpp
```

it compiles but when I run a HMAC sample, copied from this location, http://delta.affinix.com/docs/qca/mactest_8cpp-example.html#_a6

the application stuck with the following error:
**Starting C:\Qt\2010.04\qt\untitled1\release\untitled1.exe...
C:\Qt\2010.04\qt\untitled1\release\untitled1.exe exited with code -1073741515**

Commenting out some lines doesn't bring the effect. Even the first line of the HMAX Example, will lead to the results described above "QCA::Initializer init;"
I've tried the "qca-2.0.0-mingw" also, but the same effect occurres.

Greets and Thanks first,
Marco

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it builds, that's already good. If it doesn't start, usually DLLs are not found, at runtime. Try adding the path to the qca DLLs to your PATH. In creator you can configure that in the Run Environment section of your Run configuration (Project/Run Settings).

Comment: Nailed it! Thanx for your quick response.